# How to get vue's v-else-if functionality in angular?

Tags: angular, vue.js

In vue we can use conditional rendering like this:

```
<div v-if="condition1">Condition1 is true</div>
<div v-else-if="condition2">Condition2 is true</div>
<div v-else-if="condition3">Condition3 is true</div>
<div v-else>All of the above conditions are false</div>
```

How can I achive a similar functionality in angular 10?

I know that angular has *ngIf directive but as far as i know we can only achieve if; else with it and no more. I looked around and looks like I will have to implement a directive, but have no clue how to start.
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
Tried using ngSwitch.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="true">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">Condition1 is true</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="false">Condition2 is true</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="true">Condition3 is true</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>All of the above conditions are false</div>
</ng-container>
```

Gives:

```
Condition1 is true
Condition3 is true
```

Instead of just

```
Condition1 is true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a workaround using [`[ngSwitch]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) directive with `true`.

Try the following

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="true">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="condition1">Condition1 is true</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="condition2">Condition2 is true</div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="condition3">Condition3 is true</div>
  <div *ngSwitchDefault>All of the above conditions are false</div>
</ng-container>
```

### Update

You could *nest* `*ngIf` directive's `else` block to achieve a if-else-if like structure.

Try the following

```html
<div *ngIf="condition1; else condition2">Condition 1 is true</div>

<ng-template #condition2>
  <div *ngIf="condition2; else condition3">Condition 2 is true</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #condition3>
  <div *ngIf="condition3; else condition4">Condition 3 is true</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #condition4>
  <div>Condition 4 is true</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: See edit.
This acts more like series of if statements not if-else-if

Comment: @RahulRBadenkal: One of the setbacks of the workaround. You could instead try another workaround. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It works!. Thanks.
Only thing, I think it should be "else condition2" instead of "else #condition2"

Comment: @RahulRBadenkal: Overlooked it, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*ngIf="condition; else elseBlock"` to achive the same behaviour:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```

You can refer to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)

Comment: Yes it works for simple if-else conditions, but not for multiple if-else-if with say 3 or more else ifs